# JSON parsing - group by date range with JQ

Tags: json, date, grouping, aggregate, jq

I have the following JSON data :

```
{
  "data": [  
    {"date": "2018-08-22","value": 1},
    {"date": "2018-08-30","value": 2},
    {"date": "2018-09-01","value": 3},
    {"date": "2018-09-22","value": 3},
    {"date": "2018-09-28","value": 4},
    {"date": "2018-10-18","value": 5},
    {"date": "2018-10-23","value": 6}
  ]
}
```

I would like to use JQ to group data per month starting at the first value :
My month would be :

- 2018 08 22 to 2018 09 21
- 2018 09 22 to 2018 10 21
- 2018 10 22 to 2018 11 21

My expected output is the following :

```
{
  "data": [  
    {"month": "2018-08-22 to 2018-09-21","sum": 6},
    {"month": "2018-09-22 to 2018-10-21","sum": 12},
    {"month": "2018-10-23 to 2018-11-21","sum": 6}
  ]
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is easily obtained with the following helper function:

```
# $day should be the day (an integer) that defines the cutoff point;
# input should be a Y-M-D string
def bucket($day):
  def prev: if .m > 1 then .m -= 1 else .m = 12 | .y -= 1 end;
  def fmt: if .m <= 9 then "\(.y)-0\(.m)" else "\(.y)-\(.m)" end;
  capture("(?<y>[0-9]+)-(?<m>[0-9]+)-(?<d>[0-9]+)")
  | map_values(tonumber)
  | if .d >= $day then . else prev end
  | fmt ;
```

We now compute the bucket-count pairs:

```
.data
| (.[0].date | capture("(?<d>[0-9]+)$") | .d | tonumber) as $day
| reduce .[] as $pair ({};
  .[$pair.date | bucket($day)] += ($pair.value) )
```

With the sample data, this produces:

```
{
  "2018-08": 6,
  "2018-09": 12,
  "2018-10": 6
}
```

It is now a trivial matter to convert this into the desired format, and is thus left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking at this, here is an alternative solution in Unquery (disclaimer: I lead Unquery's development):
https://github.com/xcite-db/Unquery

```
{
   "#var dates": [
     "'2018-08-22'",
     "'2018-09-22'",
     "'2018-10-22'",
     "'2018-11-22'"
   ],
   "#return:data[]": {
    "#var i->%dates:[]?$to_time(<<date)<$to_time(.)":"'up to '+.",
    "%i":"$sum(value)"
   }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "up to 2018-09-22": 6,
    "up to 2018-10-22": 12,
    "up to 2018-11-22": 6
}
```